# Is there a way to check if 2 array elements match in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array in which list elements get pushes when I click on them. After 2 elements are inside of it I need a way to check them against each other and see if they are exactly the same. I've tried the basic `if(array[0] === array[1])` but that simply returns true (they match) no matter `if array[0] = li.whatever` and `array[1] = li.notTheSame` .

```
var $card1 = $clicked[0];
var $card2 = $clicked[1];
function checkMatch(){
    if ($clicked.length === 2){
        if ($card1 === $card2){
            matched();
        }else {
            $clicked.length = 0;
            $('.card').removeClass('open show');
            console.log('NOT A MATCH!')
        };
    }else{

    };
};
```

Comment: `but that simply returns true` - it shouldn't ... what is the exact contents of this `array[0]` and `array[1]` etc?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: one thing to note: you set $card1 and $card2 outside the `checkMatch` function ... so, that's a code smell

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You seem you just want to compare two values.
So, I've made a really basic function basing on what you explained on your code. Is this right one for you?

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var cards = [];

div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.target.style.background = 'green';
  cards.push(e.target.textContent);
  checkMatch();
});

function checkMatch(){
  if(cards.length <= 1){
    return;
  }
  
  if(cards[0] === cards[1]){
    alert('Same');
  }else{
    alert('Different');
  }
}
```

```css
div{
  width:500px;
}
li{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #E7F3F7;
  list-style-type:none;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Cow</li>
<li>Bird</li>
<li>Bird</li>
<li>Dog</li>
<li>Cat</li>
<li>Dog</li>
<li>Cow</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from another question I posted. 
Basically:

```
let firstCard = array[0];
let secondCard = array[1];
```

And I changed the "if" that checks the cards to this:

```
if(firstCard.children().attr('class') === secondCard.children().attr('class')){
"Do something"
}
```

And it works perfectly. It doesn't find them all as a match anymore!

Comment: Please dont base it on a classname. Instead try a data-* attribute

Comment: They all have a class of 1,2,3 then the match element has the same as 1-1 so it won't give false positives.

Comment: It's bad practice, because classes get added, others removed and you'll end up with half your JavaScript code not working, if you follow it.

Comment: Because thats not what classes are for. Seperate style and function. Class is for style, you can use data-* for function :) Might seem overkill now, but when you advance your level, it'll be better